# MySQL 8 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'tablespaces.PRIMARY' upon triggering a TRUNCATE command

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, data-integrity

I am trying to empty the content of a table using the following command:

`TRUNCATE TABLE <table_name>;`

The table engine is InnoDB.

Upon executing this command, I receive the following error:

`SQL Error [1062] [23000]: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'tablespaces.PRIMARY'`

As I keep retrying, the number of the duplicate entry increments and the error becomes, e.g.:

`SQL Error [1062] [23000]: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'tablespaces.PRIMARY'`

For context, the schema where I execute this query in does not contain a "tablespaces" table. I suspected this table could be in the `information_schema` schema and it's indeed the case, but the tablespace table is completely empty.

How to explain this and how to work around this problem?

**UPDATE**

For context, this error started appearing after a migration from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 on AWS Aurora

**UPDATE 2**

Additional context:
Even simply creating a table triggers the error as well.

I'm performing this operation on a restored snapshot (I tried using the "copy-on-write" and "full-copy" methods, with same results).

I was afraid the main DB from which the snapshot is taken was equally affected by the bug, but it's not, as I can create tables there.

Comment: Could be a damaged table, which `REPAIR TABLE` might be able to fix. In a pinch you could also clone the schema and swap it out, like `CREATE TABLE table_name_ LIKE table_name` and then `RENAME TABLE` to swap.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately REPAIR TABLE didn't work as apparently not supported by InnoDB

Comment: It's not "supported" but it does the job anyway.

Comment: `tablespaces` is a reference to the internal schema tables.

Comment: @tadman I tried it but unfortunately the error remains the same :\

Comment: Try the create with same schema approach. Not sure how that could fail.

Comment: The same error message appears in this bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=114133 but there is no verification or solution.

Comment: I've seen the same issue after migrating from mysql5.7 to mysql8 (Aurora mysql). I've also tried `CREATE TABLE LIKE` workaround but got the same issue with tablespaces.

Comment: @danijel Ah! That's exactly what we just did, exact same upgrade, on Aurora MySQL  too. I'll add it to the description. Thanks.

Comment: @tadman I tried the "CREATE LIKE" strategy and received the exact same error upon creating the table unfortunately

Comment: You're going to need to try that on another server instance. Consider using the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` with an alternate table name. How could that fail? Maybe this is some deep bug in that MySQL 8 variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was sent to me by  [@sam-weston](https://stackexchange.com/users/13880286/sam-weston), who received the information through AWS support.

It appears to be a bug introduced with version 3.05.2 of Aurora MySQL.

The bug was fixed in Aurora MySQL 3.06.0, the solution is therefore to upgrade to this version and future snapshots will not have the issue.

AWS also provided the following workaround:

> The suggested workaround is to restart the writer instance 2 times for the cache to be cleared and then the auto increment continues to work. If this workaround does not work, we kindly request that you restore the snapshot and change the version to 3.06.0 to resolve the issue. This issue has been fixed in this version.